# Custom Facebook Share Integration

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fbml

I'm working on an eCommerce website, in which the Shopping Cart page needs to have the Facebook Share button for all product items, with the following requirements:-

Let's assume that there are 4 Product Items in the shopping cart page - "p1", "p2", "p3" & "p4".

1. When the user clicks the "Share" button for "p4" item, he will be asked to login, if he is not logged into FB. This has been accomplished using the "`fb:login-button`" FBML tag.
2. After login, the user will be able to provide a Custom Message in the pop-up in my website. That pop-up will also contain the name of the Product for the "p4" item, along with an image.
3. When the user clicks the "Share" / "Submit" button, the message with the Product name & image for the "p4" item will get posted / published in the user's Facebook wall. Both the points #2 & #3 have been done using the "`FB.init`" & "FB.ui" core methods of JavaScript SDK.
4. Now in my website, the Shopping Cart page will show me that for the "p4" item, the Facebook Share is completed & so there will be no more "Facebook Share" button, even when the page is refreshed again or when more such products are added into the Shopping Cart. Here I'm not able to perform the disabling of the "Share" button.
5. The user will be able to click the "Share" button for the other products "p1", "p2" & "p3". but the pop-up for the Share message will show the Product name & image for the corresponding products & not for the last item "p4". However, here the pop-up always provides the information for only the last item "p4". Instead what I actually want is the multiple instances of the Facebook Share functionality.

I'm particularly in need of assistance for points #4 & #5.

Comment: Is there nobody who can at least answer some of the points?

Comment: Please share some code, such as how you are adding the share buttons and anything else that would be of use.

Comment: If you could share the code, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook wont allow you to share custom text/images using share button, if you need to do so, in the share URL, give URL of product detail page instead of list page and set meta-data in that product detail page.

Other option is to set meta-data generic to all products.

Here is the link explaining what are the meta-data Facebook can understand

http://grafikdesign.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/facebook-sharespecifying-meta-tags-fbml-audio-flash-video-action-bar/

Comment: Your option looks more viable to think & implement, than of the others.

Answer (score 5):

I can't address your problem in Number 4 but I think what you're trying to do is as simple as creating a facebook sharer link dynamically and style it appropriately.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg8ns/2/) that does just that, take a look here and see if that helps you.

The guts of the code is a simple jQuery event handler that configures the url for the facebook sharer and some parameters, given the following html:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li id="product-1">
        Awesome Snacks 
        <a class="sharer" href="http://www.yoursite.com/some/url/to/product-1" data-title="Awesome Snacks on Website!">
            <span class="liketext">Share</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the following jQuery event handler definition:

```
$('.sharer').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var title = $(this).data('title');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');    
    var fbSharerUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?';
    var params = { u: url, t: title };
    var fbSharerConfig = 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=600,height=400';

    window.open(fbSharerUrl + $.param(params), 'sharer', fbSharerConfig);
});
```

This will generate a facebook sharer link for you dynamically based on the href and data-title attributes of the links in your shopping cart.

Take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg8ns/2/) I linked earlier as it also includes some CSS to make the links appear like the facebook share buttons :)

Comment: nice work :) you are really helpful. Changing yoursite.com with each real product link is working perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if i am wrong, but wouldn't the use of the iframe-Share-button correct all your problems?

Comment: I believe it would be the easiest solution in this case.